# Imitating excel sheet with Dojo Grid HELP?

Tags: javascript, dojo, grid

I have a basic web page that I'm trying to capture the enter key when pressed. I will have a page with many rows( depending on what was pulled by the database ) where each field is editable. What I'm trying to do is when a user is focused on a certain column on a certain row, I want them to be able to press enter and their focus will go to the next row but stay in the same column. I'm creating my grid with Dojo Grid.

The first part of the is to figure out how to capture the enter key. 
The next part would be to figure out how to bind the javascript function to the paticular field. 
Then finally I need to be able to advace my row by 1, stay in the same column and keep my field as editable.

So, any advice on the enter key capturing?

Answer (score 1):

Is this enough? [Accessibility Improvements to the 1.3 DataGrid](http://dojotoolkit.org/2009/03/31/accessibility-improvements-1-3-datagrid):

- Scrolling with the keyboard is now
  supported.
- Enter key press will now
  invoke onrowclick event
- When in edit
  mode, pressing tab and shift/tab will
  move focus to / from other editable
  cells in edit mode on the same row
- ...